# Displaying Data From Dynamic HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, html-table

I have an HTML form that you can input values into. You can click submit then it will show the data on a confirmation page that you entered. I was having problems with displaying multiple lines of text but got that fixed. Now I have another problem...I have 3 sets of tables and whenever information is entered (specifically in the 3rd table), it copies that data into the other table...how can this be fixed??

This is the HTML for the table and looks the same for each of the 3 tables:

```
<table id="tables" cellspacing="5">
    <tr align="center" id="table_titles">
        <td>Tier</td>
        <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
        <td>Multiplier</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Retro</td>
        <td>Guaranteed</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="center" name="tier">1</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="purchase_minimum" name="rows[0][purchase_minimum]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="multiplier" name="rows[0][multiplier]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="uom" name="rows[0][uom]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="retro"  name="rows[0][retro]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="guaranteed" name="rows[0][guaranteed]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" data-name="paid" name="rows[0][paid]"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addmoreRowsbutton" value="Add row" onclick="insRow()"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This is the JAVASCRIPT for each table and is extremely similar to that of the other tables except for the `insRow()` has a different name as well as the `new_row`:

```
function insRow()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('tables');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';

  var inputs = new_row.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

  for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  {
      inputs[i].value='';
      inputs[i].name='rows[' + len + '][' + inputs[i].dataset.name + ']';
  }

  x.appendChild(new_row)
}
```

And this is the HTML/PHP confirmation page with each table having the same code:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['rows'])): ?>
    <table id="table" cellspacing="20">
        <tr align="center" id="table_row">
            <td>Tier</td>
            <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
            <td>Multiplier</td>
            <td>UOM</td>
            <td>Retro</td>
            <td>Guaranteed</td>
            <td>Paid</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $count = 1;
            foreach($_POST['rows'] as $row): 
        ?>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['purchase_minimum']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['multiplier']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['uom']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['retro']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['guaranteed']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['paid']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            $count++;
            endforeach; 
        ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: When using `id` for HTML elements the `id`'s must be unique. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: okay so I checked and I actually have different IDs in my HTML code...however, the IDs in the PHP/HTML were the same but I checked the rest of my code and I was never actually using those IDs so I don't think that was making any difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big problem in your html code: several elements have the same ids. Ids must be unique. Each table must have a different id than the other tables. Each input must have a different id than the others.

Comment: okay so I checked and I actually have different IDs in my HTML code...however, the IDs in the PHP/HTML were the same but I checked the rest of my code and I was never actually using those IDs so I don't think that was making any difference.

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Wrong, in your js `var x=document.getElementById('tables');` so your are using these Ids, and you don't know wich table is selected...

Comment: I fixed all of the IDs and I am still having the same problem unfortunately

Comment: My PHP/HTML confirmation page actually doesn't even use the Javascript as the confirmation page just pulls data from the form and displays it

Comment: @Rataiczak24 You still select another table to insert your datas in, not the right one. Your function `insRow()` shoulf first check wich table is concerned, then select the concerned table, and not another one...

Comment: Would the `echo $row` in my PHP code be the problem since that is the same for all tables?